# Matching and call data from 2 data frames in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two data frames, A and B.
First I want to match two columns from B(id and type) to A.
If they have the same elements then I want to call all the other information in A to new dataframe C.

For example

A

```
id  type  info1  info2  info3  info4   
a   t1    *      ~       ~      ~       
b   t5    *      ~       ~      ~       
c   t3    *      ~       ~      ~       
a   t2    *      ~       ~      ~       
b   t3    *      ~       ~      ~
```

B

```
id   %    type  
a    .2   t1  
b    .15  t2  
c    .1   t3
```

a and c have both same types in A and B
So I want to create a new data frame C with all the other columns which a and c have in A,

```
id type  info1  info2  info3  info4  
A  t1     *       ~      ~      ~  
C  t3     *       ~      ~      ~
```

I tried
    C = merge(A, C, by = c("type", "id"))

but I think it shows all the type and id which are both in A and B.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more why you are not satisfied with the result of `merge`? It seems to be exactly what you want or am I misunderstanding you?

Comment: Should be `C = merge(A, B, by = c("type", "id"))`, no? `B` being the second argument, not `C`. Also, why do you expect uppercase `ids` when both input `ids` are lowercase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you want to extract from A only those rows where id and type match in B. You can use merge for this:

```
C <- merge(A,B[,c("id","type")])
C
#   id type info1 info2 info3 info4
# 1  a   t1     *     ~     ~     ~
# 2  c   t3     *     ~     ~     ~
```

You don't need `by=...` in this because the only columns in the second argument are `id` and `type`, and merge works on all common columns by default.